# A specific post call is called twice?

Tags: javascript, angular, http

I have an app, and there is many place where we execute post request call.

But, in one place in the application, a call is executed twice :

in my service I have

```
PostNewStory(params:API_TYPE.post_new_item_history_call){
    let observable$ = this._http.Get(UtilsService.apiServer + '/post_new_item_history', params)
    let subscription = observable$.subscribe((data:any) =>{
        //do stuff
        subscription.unsubscribe();
    });
    return observable$;
}
```

In My component I have

```
PostComment(){
    const params = {
       //params
    };

    this._itemDetailsService.PostNewStory(params).subscribe((data:post_new_item_history_response) => {
        this.ResetCommentArea();
    });
}
```

I have an HttpService like following

```
public Post<T>(url: string, payload: any): Observable<T>;
public Post<T>(url, payload): Observable<T> {
    return this.http.post<T>(url, payload, httpHeaders)
    .pipe(
        retry(MAX_RETRY)
    )
}
```

This works perfectly everywhere, I checked, every function is called Once, and only once. If I put a log here =>

```
public Post<T>(url: string, payload: any): Observable<T>;
public Post<T>(url, payload): Observable<T> {
    console.log("MyLog")
    return this.http.post<T>(url, payload, httpHeaders)
    .pipe(
        retry(MAX_RETRY)
    )
}
```

I do have only one log. But the call is done twice ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are subscribing to the http request observable twice, once in `PostNewStory`, then you return the observable, and subscribe to it again in `PostComment`.

Try something like this :

```
PostNewStory(params:API_TYPE.post_new_item_history_call){
  let observable$ = this._http.Get(UtilsService.apiServer + '/post_new_item_history', params)
  return observable$.pipe(
    map((data: any) => {
      // do stuff
      return dataNeededInPostCommentMethod;
    }),
  );
}
```

Comment: I am going to check this, thank you for the explanation. Quick Qeustion, no need to unsubscribe ?

Comment: In general it depends on the type of `Observable` you are subscribing to, but for an HTTP request, you don't need to unsubscribe.